# Simple http server in nodejs: response time 1 millisecond is a lot?

Tags: node.js, performance, fastify

I wrote the simplest http server on a `nodejs` (v15.11) and `fastify` (v3.20.2) (as one of the most productive libraries on a node for this purpose). And the results are somewhat depressing for me:

- when sending 1 request, response time +/- 1 millisecond
- when sending 10 concurrent requests, the average response time = 5.6 milliseconds

```
Min time: 4 msec 5 µsec 800 nsec
Max time: 5 msec 913 µsec 200 nsec
Avg time: 5 msec 560 µsec 150 nsec
```

- when sending 100 concurrent requests, the average response time = 41 milliseconds

```
Min time: 21 msec 212 µsec 300 nsec
Max time: 41 msec 570 µsec 300 nsec
Avg time: 40 msec 918 µsec 113 nsec
```

It seems to me that for a server that does nothing, these are VERY large timings. Maybe I'm doing something wrong? What are your thoughts on this?

Source code:

```js
// server.js
const server = require('fastify')({ keepAliveTimeout: 20000 })

server.get('/ping', async (req, res) => {
  res.code(200).send('')
})

server.listen(3000)
```

```js
// benchmark.js
const http = require('http')

const ITER = 100
const agent = new http.Agent({ keepAlive: true, maxFreeSockets: 500 })
const { hrtime } = process

console.log('Starting benchmark...')
const hrStart = hrtime.bigint()

makeRequest(0)             // make 1 request for a handshake
  .then(() => start(ITER)) // start benchmark
  .then(results => {       // display benchmark results
    console.log(`Benchmark finished in ${stringify(hrtime.bigint() - hrStart)}`)
    const min = results.reduce((res, v) => Math.min(res, v), Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER)
    const max = results.reduce((res, v) => Math.max(res, v), 0)
    const total = results.reduce((res, v) => res + v, 0)
    console.log(`Min time: ${stringify(min)}`)
    console.log(`Max time: ${stringify(max)}`)
    console.log(`Avg time: ${stringify(Math.round(total / ITER))}`)
  })


async function start(iterCount) {
  const results = new Array(ITER) // an array of elapsed time for each request
  for(let nIter = 0; nIter < iterCount; ++nIter) {
    results[nIter] = makeRequest(nIter).then(({ iter, elapsed }) => results[iter] = elapsed)
  }
  return Promise.all(results).then(() => results)
}

function makeRequest(iter) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    const start = hrtime.bigint()
    http.get('http://localhost:3000/ping', { agent } , res => {
      res.resume().on('end', () => resolve({ iter, elapsed: Number(hrtime.bigint() - start) }))
    })
  })
}

function stringify(time) {
  time = Number(time)
  if(Number.isNaN(time)) {
    throw new Error(`time is not a number`)
  }
  const nsec = time % 1000
  time = (time - nsec) / 1000
  const mcsec = time % 1000
  time = (time - mcsec) / 1000
  const msec = time
  return `${msec} msec ${mcsec} µsec ${nsec} nsec`
}
```

Comment: So, let's say (for the sake of argument) that one of these requests takes about 1ms of CPU nodejs time (which your individual test kind of shows).  And, we know that nodejs runs your Javascript in a single thread.  So, if you send 100 simultaneous requests and there is nothing asynchronous in your processing of them, they will get processed one after another.  The first one will take 1ms, the last one about 100ms and the average would be about 50ms.  Not too far off from what you measured.  I'm not sure what you're surprised by.

Comment: Your assumption is incorrect, since all requests go asynchronously (the last line in the function `start()`: `Promise.all(results).then(() => results)`). Also in my opinion 1 millisecond is a lot for a simple empty response. It shouldn't take more than 200-300 microseconds

Comment: Perhaps you didn't follow that all your Javascript in the server is run single threaded so regardless of the use of `Promise.all()`, it still only runs one piece of your Javascript at a time (single threaded) and some of your Javascript is involved in handling every single incoming request in your server.  So, it can only be sending one response at a time.  The nodejs architecture is such that if you want to handle a higher volume of simultaneous requests, you need to configure it so it can use more cores for running your Javascript and one way to do that would be to use the cluster module.

Comment: I might also mention that if you want the fastest server at serving empty responses, you don't want nodejs.  That is not what it is best at.  Now, if your requests are all going to be I/O bound (like database or file system), then I'd pit nodejs against many other web servers for how well it handles lots of I/O requests because of its asynchronous I/O model.

Comment: Okay, I agree with you about requests with a quantity more than 1. But 1ms for one empty request is very time consuming :-(

Comment: Remove the unnecessary `async (req, res)` async keyword: you will do an event loop cycle less.
I would use autocannon to measure the througput

Comment: thanks, forgot to remove after simplifying the server function `ping`. But I think the node engine ignores `async` in the case when there is no `await` inside the function.

Comment: I think there are too many variables here (pc setup mainly). You should set a baseline, for example with the default HTTP server provided by node.js. Then you could compare them in percentage.

Comment: Here an example of [how your pc setup](https://github.com/fastify/fastify/issues/3027#issuecomment-824940937) can impact your benchmark

Comment: As mentioned before NodeJS has a single threaded event loop. So yes it can do async tasks, you can try to do a profiler to pin point bottlenecks. That being said, you can scale horizontally by running multiple instances in front of a load balancer (or using the node cluster feature). Or using worker threads if you want to offload heavy tasks to separate threads.